# Select results that are only between today and 2 days in the future

Tags: php, mysql

I'm so confused with working with dates. How can I write this query so it only selects results that are between today and 2 days in the future?

The date is stored in a column named EstimatedTime (with a "text" type...) like this 201502181150

```
<?php 

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE Status = "D" ORDER BY id DESC');

/*
$Date = 201502181150;
$time_ahead = date('M d', strtotime($Date. ' + 2 days'));
// The above returns Feb 20, but how can I do this on MySQL?
*/

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . date('M d', strtotime($row['EstimatedTime'])) . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you so much.

Comment: What is a type of `EstimatedTime` column?

Comment: The EstimatedTime column has a "text" type. Not sure why, but I'm just working with it.

Comment: If you can't modify the column type to a `timestamp` or similar type (recommended) you should consult mysql's documentation about converting text to timestamps and using this on the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `EstimatedTime` column is declared as datatype `DATETIME` or `DATE`, then it's straightforward:

```
WHERE t.EstimatedTime >= DATE(NOW())
  AND t.EstimatedTime  < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

`NOW()` returns the current date and time, the `DATE()` function trims off the time portion, making it equivalent to midnight.

---

If the column is declared as character type, rather than `DATETIME` (but why in God's green earth would you do that?), convert the `DATETIME` expression to character in an appropriate canonical format, so that string comparisons will work appropriately:

```
WHERE t.EstimatedTime >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW())                 ,'%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
  AND t.EstimatedTime  < DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
```

If `EstimatedTime` is stored as a numeric (integer) datatype, then convert the string to numeric by adding a zero...

```
WHERE t.EstimatedTime >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW())                 ,'%Y%m%d%H%i%s')+0
  AND t.EstimatedTime  < DATE_FORMAT(DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%Y%m%d%H%i%s')+0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function and add interval:

```
select str_to_date('201502181150', '%Y %m %d');
```

so your query will be look:

```
WHERE str_to_date(t.EstimatedTime, '%Y %m %d') >= date(now()) 
  AND str_to_date(t.EstimatedTime, '%Y %m %d') < date(now()) + interval 2 day
```

Comment: This approach will work, but wrapping the `EstimatedTime` column in a function disallows MySQL from using an efficient range scan operation (using an undex with `EstimatedTime` as the leading column... that function has to be evaluate for *every* row in the table. For performance, we prefer to perform the conversion on the literal side, because the evaluation only has to be performed once.

Comment: Thanks for explain. Good to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP soltion:
Is the value `201502181150` the date in milliseconds? If so, just treat it like an integer and add `1000*60*60*24*2` which is 2 days. You can do it like this:

```
$t = (int)$row['EstimatedTime'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE EstimatedTime > $t AND EstimatedTime < ". ($t+1000*60*60*24*2) ." ORDER BY id DESC"
```

But it is kind of way around as You have to execute 2 MySQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
<?php

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE Status = "D" ORDER BY id DESC');

$currDate = time();

//$time_ahead = Current Date + 2 Days (172800 seconds = 2 days)
$time_ahead = $currDate + 172800;

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if (!strtotime($row['EstimatedTime'] < $currDate || !strtotime($row['EstimatedDate'] > $time_ahead))) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . date('M d', strtotime($row['EstimatedTime'])) . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

?>
```